# Apply view attributes to other view

Tags: android

Is it possible to apply attributes of one view that is defined via xml to other view that is creating programmatically?

In my case situation is next -

There is custom view FormField:

```
class FormField extends LinearLayout {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
       super.onFinishInflate();
       final int childCount = getChildCount();
       if (childCount > 1) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("FormField can store only one child view");
       }
       labelView = new TextView(getContext());
       addView(labelView, 0);
    }
```

with next target usage:

```
<com.korovyansk.android.views.FormField
    style="@style/Label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Field label"
    android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

    <com.korovyansk.android.views.EditText
        style="@style/TextField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

</com.korovyansk.android.views.FormField>
```

So the idea is to transfer attributes (style, text, margins) from FormField to TextView created dynamically in onFinishInflated method.

Comment: In the constructor of `FormField` you get the attributes of the view and you could then, later, apply them to the `TextView`.

Comment: @Luksprog I tried it, it works good for layout_margin* parameters, but doesn't work for text, not sure about style.

Comment: How do you try to get the text attribute? `context.obtainStyledAttributes()` should allow you to get the text.

Comment: @Luksprog I tried to save AttributeSet that are passed to constructor of TextField, and later construct TextView with TextView(Context, AttributeSet) constructor.

Comment: Looks like somewhere parameters are filtered, but I cannot find exact place in the source of Android.

Comment: I was able to solve my concrete case using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013971/how-to-use-standard-attribute-androidtext-in-my-custom-view, but as side effect I noticed a bit of magic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650879/magic-with-obtainstyledattributes-method