# Magic with obtainStyledAttributes method

Tags: android

Code:

```
public class CustomLayoutWithText extends LinearLayout {

    private Context context;
    private AttributeSet attrs;

    public CustomLayoutWithText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        this.attrs = attrs;
        fooAttrs();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        fooAttrs();
    }

    private void fooAttrs() {
        int[] set = {
            android.R.attr.text        // idx 0
        };
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, set);
        Log.d(null, a.getString(0));
    }
}
```

and XML:

```
<com.korovyansk.android.views.CustomLayoutWithText
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Some text"/>
```

**Reasonable to expect that output will be:**
    Some text 
    Some text

**But it's:**
    Some text
    null

**Why second time it appears null? And how to avoid it?**

Comment: dump attrs and see if they change

Comment: @pskink attrs is huge object, hashCode returns the same value, but maybe its not overrided. what method to use for dump, toString or something else?

Comment: use getAttributeName/getAttributeValue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all data in `attrs` gets recycled. In fact in the examples everywhere they recommend to explicitly recycle all obtained typed arrays from the `AttributeSet` in constructor of the View. I think you should follow the best practice too.

```
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, set);
    try {
        // read attributes from a
        // ...
    } finally {
        attributes.recycle();
    }
```

My guess is that when `onFinishInflate()` is called, `attrs` is already empty or unavailable.

In fact, according to the code of `LayoutInflater`, the `AttributeSet` that is passed into View constructor during layout inflation is actually based on `XmlPullParser`. The `onFinishInflate()` is called on the parent view after inflating all of its children.

It looks like at this point in 'onFinishInflate()' you cannot obtain the values of your attribute from the `attrs`. Especially if you have children inside your layout - the `attrs` will reference to the same parser, but the parser's position will point to the attributes of the last parsed child.