# Butterknife custom view unbind

Tags: android, android-view, butterknife

What's the best practice for calling : -

```
Butterknife.unbind()
```

in a custom Android view please?

Answer (score 26):

Yes, `onDetachedFromWindow` is the right function as mentioned in [NJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794969/1016544) because this is where view no longer has a surface for drawing.

But the usage is incorrectly mentioned in the answer. The right approach involves binding in `onFinishInflate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

and unbinding in `onDetachedFromWindow`:

```
@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    // View is now detached, and about to be destroyed
    unbinder.unbind();
}
```

Comment: is it necesary to bind when in a custom view ? i dont unbind in a fragment why do i need to do this in the view ? im just wondering if its required for clean up or why bother unbinding ?

Comment: @j2emanue If you need to null out views and null out listeners then you better call unbind in a custom view. It's not needed but a recommended approach. 

You should also unbind in Fragment.  Jake Wharton mentioned the reason here: `
There can be a case when fragment's view is destroyed, but the fragment instance is still present. For example, when fragment goes into the back stack - onDestroyView() is called, but onDestroy() is not.` 
source: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/291

Comment: @j2emanue Here is better explanation why to nullify views in `onDestroyView();` http://stackoverflow.com/a/26370042/1307690
@WahibUlHaq I'm not shure if you have to do this in `onDetachedFromView()` because your custom view at this point will not be yet null, and if you try to change childs of this after unbind you`l get NullPointerException

Comment: I wonder then if it's better to unbind in oncreateview just before you bind?

Answer (score 10):

Try in `onDetachedFromWindow()`

```
Unbinder unbinder;
unbinder = Butterknife.bind(this, root);
```

and in `onDetachedFromWindow` you need to call `unbinder.unbind();`

```
@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    // View is now detached, and about to be destroyed
   unbinder.unbind()
}
```

Comment: That's the right approach, although be careful with that, because `onDetachedFromWindow` callback does not necessarily have to mean that the `View` is about to be destroyed (e.g. if it's a part of `RecyclerView`).

Comment: @BartekLipinski What is the right approach for custom view in a ViewHolder. Calling unbind in onDetachedFromWindow() is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

`onDetachedFromWindow` won't always work, like if the custom view is within a `RecyclerView`. Adding that in fact actually crashed my app. Honestly, it worked fine without unbinding it.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning!**

If you set attributes with `app:attribute="value"` in XML, you will lose their values when reading with:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this);

    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, R.styleable.YourStyleable);
    try {
        int number = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.YourStyleable_number, 0);
        image.setImageResource(number);

        String text = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.YourStyleable_text);
        text.setText(text);
    } finally {
        typedArray.recycle();
    }
}
```

Their values will be 0 and null. Initialize them in custom view's constructor.

A reason is using `obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data` instead of `obtainStyledAttributes(attrs`.

See: [Magic with obtainStyledAttributes method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650879/magic-with-obtainstyledattributes-method/27219140).