# Where to call bind and unbind method in custom view when using ButterKnife?

Tags: android, butterknife

I'm new to Android. I wrote a custom view, but I just don't know where to call the `bind` and `unbind` method. I have searched for [this documentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/). And it seemingly suggests to use `bind` in the `onFinishInflate()` callback. But I `bind` the view in its constructor function and there is no crash any way. Is it correct? And how about the `unbind`? I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794872/butterknife-custom-view-unbind/36794969), it suggests to use `unbind` in the `onDetachedFromWindow()` callback. Is it required or necessary?

```
public class BloodIndicatorView extends FrameLayout {
    @Bind(R.id.ll_record_bloodpress)
    LinearLayout llRecordBloodpress;
    @Bind(R.id.ll_record_bloodsugar)
    LinearLayout llRecordBloodsugar;

    private Context mContext;

    public BloodIndicatorView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public BloodIndicatorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, -1);
    }

    public BloodIndicatorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.health_blood_indicator, this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    public void update() {

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.ll_record_bloodpress)
    public void recordBloodpress() {
        Intent intent = BloodPressActivity.getIntent2Act(mContext);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.ll_record_bloodsugar)
    public void recordBloodsugar() {
        Intent intent = BloodSugarActivity.getIntent2Act(mContext);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the view inside the class which you are doing correctly and since there is no error that means ButterKnife.bind(this); is happening correctly. And its not necessary to unbind this should work completely fine.