# How to use android namespace attr in a custom view

Tags: android

When using the custom view, it seems that the android namespace attr extend from parent view can't be use. I think it not reasonable.
Here is my code:

```
int[] set = {
    android.R.attr.src // idx 0 use the android: tag attr
};
final TypedArray b = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, set);
BitmapDrawable drawable1 = (BitmapDrawable)b.getDrawable(0);
mIconBitmap = drawable1.getBitmap();
b.recycle();
```

and the activity is:

```
<com.example.ling.fragmenttest.TabImage
    xmlns:tabImage="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.ling.fragmenttest"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_image"
    tabImage:tabColor="#FF33B5E5"
    tabImage:tabSrc="@drawable/ic_friend"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

I just want to use the android:src attr in java file. But the getDrawable() return null instead of ic_setting. By the way, my view is extend from ImageView.

I find one similar with my situation:[[How to use standard attribute android:text in my custom view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013971/how-to-use-standard-attribute-androidtext-in-my-custom-view][1])
But why I get the null.....Please help me out~

Comment: this may help you http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: you need that image in your java file

Comment: I have add that image in my drawable folder

Comment: In the create-view page, google explain how to get the custom attr, not the android namespace attr.

Comment: `a.getDrawable(R.styleable.TabImage_android_src);` via. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33014367/1819810