# How to change text from constructor in custom Button

Tags: android, android-button

I have a custom Button view. Where I want to get the current text from attributes, modify it and show it.

```
public class GreenRoundedButton extends AppCompatButton {

public GreenRoundedButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.GreenRoundedButton);
    CharSequence t = a.getText(R.styleable.GreenRoundedButton_android_text);
    a.recycle();

    this.setText("something  else");
}
```

Currently, I'm able to get the `android:text` attribute ([SO answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33014367/2145504)r) but I cannot reassign to any other value.

Is there a different way to do this than `setText()`?

Comment: I am not exactly sure of what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want to modify the text in the attributes? Or do you want to assign it as the text of your button?

Comment: and whats wrong with `TextView#setText()` method?

Comment: @pskink it does not work

Comment: @markusian any of them would work for me

Comment: @kike So, `setText(t)` does not work? What do you get?

Comment: It does nothing. The Button keeps the android:text attribute

Comment: My apologies. The error was in another part of the code, TextView#setText() works perfect.